# Error 0xc000007b when launching mongod.exe / mongo.exe

Tags: windows, mongodb

Installed mongodb on Windows.

**Mongodb:** 3.4.3 - Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit, with SSL support x64

**OS:** Windows 7 64-bit

When I run mongod.exe or mongo.exe this error occurs

**The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application**

What can I do to get rid of this error? 
Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: getting same issue, is there any solution ?

Comment: @JosephM after updating **Visual C++ Redistributable** i got rid of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got rid of this error by updating **`Visual C++ Redistributable`**. But note that before this i also updated my **`Net Framework`**, **`DirectX`** and drivers for video-card.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to my Computer
2. Properties (Under windows edition check if service pack 1 is listed)
3. If not, make sure you have following windows updates installed on your system:

> KB958488 (dot NET Framework) (<=10mb) (msu file)
>
> KB2533552 (a prerequisite for service pack 1) (<=10mb) (msu file)
>
> KB976932 (service pack 1) (around 900 mb) (exe file)
>
> KB2999226 (Visual C++) (<=2mb) (msu file)

4. Add your mongo db bin directory to `Path` (Environment variable):

> Example >>> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin

Go to control panel → system and security → system → advanced system settings → advanced → environment variable → system variables → Path

5. Restart your system
6. Create a file `C:\data\db`
7. then run `cmd`
8. change directory to mongodb bin
9. run `mongod`

Enjoy....

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with mongodb 3.6.5 version on my windows 7. I tried updating .net and vc++, nothing worked. Then I downloaded and installed an older version of mongodb, version 3.2 and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I have the issue while running mongod  (Error 0xc000007b when launching mongod.exe / mongo.exe).

I solve the problem by using these following steps

1 step:uninstall the latest version of mongodb currently (4.2).

2 step: install mongodb version(3.0.15) don't worry its running all the feature that given by 4.2.

3 step:install the mongodb 3.0.15 in installing it gives the option (complete ,custom and other) you select the complete option and install.

4 step: Go to the program file check the mongodb folder inside the mongodb folder go to bin and run the mongod application .On this time the error will gone..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by installing **all** the Microsoft Visual C++ re distribute files .
i.e. all the versions .
You need correct version to run mongo 2013 and 15 didnt work but 2019 did .